# Generating an XML table from mysql database using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

What is wrong with this code inside HTML (Codeigniter view)? It is supposed to generate an VML file from database sales invoice information.

```
<?php
    $this->load->helper('xml');
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $this->load->helper('file'); 
    $this->load->database();

    $report = $query = $this->db->get('invoices_salesvan_warehouse');
    $new_report = $this->dbutil->xml_from_result($report);
    write_file(‘xml_file.xml’,$new_report); 
?>
```

Comment: `$report = $query = $this->db->get('invoices_salesvan_warehouse');` Looks wrong. Try doing just `$query = $this->db->get('invoices_salesvan_warehouse');` and set `$new_report =$this->dbutil->xml_from_result($query);`

Comment: `‘xml_file.xml’` what kind of quotes are you using here? shouldn't it be just single quotes? `'xml_file.xml'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
  function getDataForXML(){

   return $query = $this->db->get('invoices_salesvan_warehouse');

}  

function getreport()
{
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $report = $this->getDataForXML();
    $new_report = $this->dbutil->xml_from_result($report);
    write_file('xmlfile.xml',$new_report);
}
```

Comment: Error resolved. Reason was the location of the php opening and closing tags inside html. Thanks.